# Range for loop not working

Tags: java

I have a `Double[] foo` and I need to transform every element in the array:

I tried

```
for (Double p : foo){
    p = p * m + o;
}
```

where `m` and `o` are scaling factors. I also tried

```
for (Double p : foo){
    p *= m;
    p += o;
}
```

but neither of these are working. What am I doing wrong? I thought that all non-primitives are references in Java.

Comment: What kind of failure do you experience?

Comment: Please show your full code and the error you get (wrong output or compilation). From what you posted, you probably rather have a `double[]` to which autoboxing is applied.

Comment: @Bathsheba      mean :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Please explain to me how that is in anyway constructive...

Comment: It's a reasonable question. What looks like valid code is not working as would be expected.

Comment: @Bathsheba My apologies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java's *autoboxing* and *unboxing* is getting in the way here. Essentially `p` is *unboxed* to the primitive prior to the arithmetic operations then *autoboxed* to the wrapper type afterwards. The effect of this is that a value copy is taken and therefore modification has no effect on the original container element.

You need to recode the loop in the normal way

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; ++i){
    foo[i] = foo[i] * m + o;
}
```

Comment: Autoboxing isn't really the problem here. The problem is that `p` is a local, not a reference to the spot in the array (which Java doesn't support anyway). Even if it were a real object, assigning `p = anything ` wouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 10):

You can't change array values with an enhanced for loop, only iterate through them.

Try a normal for loop and see what happens :)

Comment: Thanks! Good to be here.